# Efficient way to read file line count on GCS bucket

Tags: java, python, linux, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to read file line count from remote server using Java Storage client.

Also tried `gsutil cat gs://{bucket_name}/file.txt | wc -l`

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

GCS does not provide a built in way to count the lines in an object.  Fundamentally at some point you will need to scan the file to count the lines. There are a few situations where there may be better ways than doing it in the way you suggest in the question:

- You could save the number of lines in [object metadata](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata). This means you only ever need to do the count one time, and can retrieve it from metadata. If you control the upload process, you could even do this at upload time so you can get the count without ever retrieving the lines.
- You could write a small [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) endpoint to do this. This has the advantage that the data never leaves GCP (and if you set it up right, never leaves the region) so is faster and has lower egress cost.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is no way using Google Storage API to get count of objects stored inside a bucket. The closest you can get is by using `BucketListOption` with `pageSize = Long.MAX_VALUE` ([here's](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage/blob/master/google-cloud-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.java#L939) the method).

However, with command line, you can execute the following command:

```
gsutil ls gs://bucket/** | wc -l
```

This will give you the required count.

Comment: Through the client library, there is no way to achieve this directly. You would need to download the object and then count the lines inside it.